# Unable to authentication a user with spring custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to authenticate a user on login request with username and password comparing from database using jpa but some how the authentication fails and returns 401 error.

The request flow is as follows:

Request from client side:

```
login: function(data,success, error){
    $http.post('auth', data).success(success).error(error);
}
```

application.yml is configured to accept request for `"auth"` as

```
    # config context path to "/" by setting an empty string
    server:
      contextPath:

    # JACKSON
    spring:
      jackson:
        serialization:
          INDENT_OUTPUT: true

    jwt:
      header: Authorization
      secret: mySecret
      expiration: 604800
      route:
        authentication:
          path: auth
          refresh: refresh

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework:
      security: DEBUG
```

Web security:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity

.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registration").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }
```

I am not sure how the flow is going through but the request comes to `createAuthenticationToken()` method in the below class and prints this line `System.out.println("Authenticate called in createAuthenticationToken");` but doesn't call the `authenticationManager.authenticate()` which is right after that even though I am able to print credentials from `JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest` bean.

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationRestController {

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "${jwt.route.authentication.path}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, Device device) throws AuthenticationException {
        System.out.println("Authenticate called in createAuthenticationToken"); //PRINTS THIS LINE

        // THIS IS NOT CALLED
        final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                        authenticationRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        System.out.println("authenticationManager.authenticate(JWTAuthRequest) is=" + authentication); //THIS IS NOT PRINTED
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        // Reload password post-security so we can generate token
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        System.out.println("userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername->userDetails is->" + userDetails);
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails, device);
        System.out.println("jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails, device) is->" + token);

        // Return the token
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(token));
    }
}
```

From here on it goes to custom entry point and returns 401 error to client. Why isn't it authenticating the user and returning a token even though the credentials are present? What am I doing wrong?

Entry point:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8970718410437077606L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ENTRY POINT"); //PRINTS THIS
        // This is invoked when user tries to access a secured REST resource without supplying any credentials
        // We should just send a 401 Unauthorized response because there is no 'login page' to redirect to
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

I have got the above code concept from https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo.git

**update**

Up on enabling debug logs in application.yml I get this error:

```
2016-11-17 00:57:10.175 DEBUG 4492 --- [io-8084-exec-39] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-11-17 00:57:10.253 DEBUG 4492 --- [io-8084-exec-39] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
2016-11-17 00:57:10.406 DEBUG 4492 --- [io-8084-exec-39] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: null
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.zerhusen.security.controller.AuthenticationRestController.createAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationRestController.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393) ~[org-netbeans-modules-web-httpmonitor.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.zerhusen.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:59) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.zerhusen.security.JwtUserFactory.create(JwtUserFactory.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.zerhusen.security.service.JwtUserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(JwtUserDetailsServiceImpl.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 103 common frames omitted

2016-11-17 00:57:10.421 DEBUG 4492 --- [io-8084-exec-39] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Calling Authentication entry point.
ENTRY POINT
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken,

```
/**
 * This constructor can be safely used by any code that wishes to create a
 * <code>UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken</code>, as the {@link
 * #isAuthenticated()} will return <code>false</code>.
 *
 */
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
    super(null);
    this.principal = principal;
    this.credentials = credentials;
    setAuthenticated(false);
}

/**
 * This constructor should only be used by <code>AuthenticationManager</code> or <code>AuthenticationProvider</code>
 * implementations that are satisfied with producing a trusted (i.e. {@link #isAuthenticated()} = <code>true</code>)
 * authentication token.
 *
 * @param principal
 * @param credentials
 * @param authorities
 */
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(authorities);
    this.principal = principal;
    this.credentials = credentials;
    super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
}
```

Your code only seems to be setting the username and password. To authenticate, you need to pass in 3 parameters - username, password and a collection of granted authorities. If you have this, pass it. Else, pass null as a third parameter.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: But I have the roles for each user assigned on registration. While login I think I don't have to set roles. It should be fetched from database I guess. I have enabled the debug logs and I get some error. Please check the updated question

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the issue was something else. I fixed it. tx

Comment: @Satyadev how did you fix this?? i am running into similar situtation??

Comment: @YogenRai I don't remember how I did it. It was a sample project I was working on for practice. I will check if I still have that project with me.

Comment: @Satyadev i would grateful to you for your help!! :)

Comment: I had a similar problem and surrounded the code that was not working with a try catch to log the error message. I could thus find the problem: my authorities were not being fetched.